# Combine integers into a long

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation, concatenation, long-integer

I need to somehow concatenate a series of 8 integers into a single long in Java. The values of the integers are between 0-255. They have to be combined in this manner: Lets say we got this sample of integers (in binary):

00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111

00000000 00000000 00000000 11111101

00000000 00000000 00000000 11110111

00000000 00000000 00000000 10111111

00000000 00000000 00000000 11110011

00000000 00000000 00000000 10111111

00000000 00000000 00000000 01111111

00000000 00000000 00000000 00111111

The resulting float will have to be:

11111111 11111101 11110111 10111111 11110011 10111111 01111111 00111111

Is this somehow achievable in Java?
I have tried using bytes instead of integers but in Java, bytes (and probably every other data type) are signed, so I had to convert them to integers as I can't deal with negative numbers, as I ll need to use them as arguments in another function. I am obligated to try to find a solution this way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ByteBuffer:

```
byte[] a = new byte[8];
a[0] = (byte) 255;
a[1] = (byte) 253;
a[2] = (byte) 247;
a[3] = (byte) 191;
a[4] = (byte) 243;
a[5] = (byte) 191;
a[6] = (byte) 127;
a[7] = (byte)  63;

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(a);
System.out.println(buffer.getLong());
// Result:
// 11111111 11111101 11110111 10111111 11110011 10111111 01111111 00111111
```

Another way to create a ByteBuffer:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Byte.SIZE);
buffer.put(0, (byte) 255);
buffer.put(1, (byte) 253);
// ...
buffer.put(7, (byte)  63);
System.out.println(buffer.getLong());
```

Also, you can use the `getLong(...)` method implementation separately without creating a ByteBuffer instance:

```
long result = getLong(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]);
System.out.println(result);
// Result:
// 11111111 11111101 11110111 10111111 11110011 10111111 01111111 00111111

long getLong(byte b7, byte b6, byte b5, byte b4, byte b3, byte b2, byte b1, byte b0) {
    return ((((long) b7       ) << 56) |
            (((long) b6 & 0xff) << 48) |
            (((long) b5 & 0xff) << 40) |
            (((long) b4 & 0xff) << 32) |
            (((long) b3 & 0xff) << 24) |
            (((long) b2 & 0xff) << 16) |
            (((long) b1 & 0xff) <<  8) |
            (((long) b0 & 0xff)      ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
long  result = 0
int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    result |= values[i] << i*8;
```

The `|=` is a *OR and set* operator, `<<` is the left shift, and `i*8` is the offset in the long.

Comment: I need a single long variable containing all the data.

Comment: @kalmer12 that would be `result`

Answer (score -1):

Here are the building blocks to help you build your own answer:

1) Getting the binary representation of your integer as String:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(x)
```

2) Shifting bits pattern *x*, *y* bits to the left:

```
x << y
```

3) Taking 2 bit patterns *x* and *y* of equal length and performing the logical inclusive OR operation:

```
x | y
```

4) Getting the binary representation of your long as String:

```
Long.toBinaryString(x)
```

Below is a possible solution (with extra methods for displaying the output), based on defined requirements:

```
public class Integers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integers integers = new Integers();
        long result = integers.toLong(255, 253, 247, 191, 243, 191, 127, 63);
        System.out.println(integers.toBinaryStringWithPadding(result));
    }

    private long toLong(int... input) {
        if (input.length != 8) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        long result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(toBinaryStringWithPadding(input[i]) + "\n");
            result |= input[i];
            result <<= 8;
        }

        System.out.println(toBinaryStringWithPadding(input.length - 1) + "\n");
        result |= input[input.length - 1];

        return result;
    }

    private String toBinaryStringWithPadding(int value) {
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
        int padding = 32 - binaryString.length();

        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(32 + 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            if (i < padding) {
                tmp.append('0');
            } else {
                tmp.append(binaryString.charAt(i - padding));
            }

            if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 8 == 0) {
                tmp.append(' ');
            }
        }

        return tmp.toString();
    }

    private String toBinaryStringWithPadding(long value) {
        String binaryString = Long.toBinaryString(value);
        int padding = 64 - binaryString.length();

        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(64 + 7);
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (i < padding) {
                tmp.append('0');
            } else {
                tmp.append(binaryString.charAt(i - padding));
            }

            if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 8 == 0) {
                tmp.append(' ');
            }
        }

        return tmp.toString();
    }

}
```